# Output alias in MySQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, debugging, database-design

I'm trying to create a query. The query is part of a work-planning system, and is used to find out how many hours each user of the system is allocated per day, on all jobs except for the one being currently viewed.

I want the output to have nicely named Aliases, such as hours_mon, hours_tue etc.

Currently the query is as follows:

`SELECT SUM(alloc.hours), alloc.day 
FROM grwp_allocations AS alloc 
LEFT JOIN grwp_jobs AS job ON (job.id = alloc.job_id AND job.id != '3') 
WHERE alloc.user_id = '35' 
AND alloc.deleted = '0' 
AND alloc.acknowledged = '0' 
GROUP BY alloc.day`

Which works fine, but I really want to replace 'SUM(alloc.hours)' with hours_...

I've tried the following but it throws up and error

`SELECT SUM(alloc.hours) AS CONCAT('hours_',alloc.day), alloc.day`

Table schema:
grwp_allocations:

- id
- job_id
- user_id
- day
- hours

grwp_jobs:

- id

Remember, I want data to be available as the following at the end:

hours_mon, hours_tue, hours_wed etc.. where 'mon','tue','wed' etc are the values from the DAY field and the value of the alias is the (summed) hours.

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you need a prepared statement.

Comment: How would a PS help? I'm running the query dynamically for each user in the system.

Comment: this mat help u http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't make a lot of sense.

You **EITHER** want an `hours_per_day` column, which will generate data like:

```
hours_per_day  |  day
---------------+-------
10             |  mon
9              |  tue
```

this is obviously an easy fix, just renaming the SUM column in your query:

```
SELECT SUM(alloc.hours) AS hours_per_day`
```

**OR**

you want a column per day of the week (`hours_mon`,`hours_tue`...) which will require a completely different query - *not just different column names!* This case is called a PIVOT table, and will look like this:

```
user | mon | tue | wed
-----+-----+-----+----
 35  | 10  |  9  |  0
```

For instructions on how to achieve this in MySQL go to: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1339#78

One of the options they show there would be something like:

```
SELECT alloc.user_id AS user,
       SUM(IF(alloc.day = 'mon',alloc.hours,0)) as mon,
       SUM(IF(alloc.day = 'tue',alloc.hours,0)) as tue,
       SUM(IF(alloc.day = 'wed',alloc.hours,0)) as wed,
       SUM(IF(alloc.day = 'thu',alloc.hours,0)) as thu,
       SUM(IF(alloc.day = 'fri',alloc.hours,0)) as fri
FROM grwp_allocations AS alloc
LEFT JOIN grwp_jobs AS job ON (job.id = alloc.job_id AND job.id != '3')
WHERE alloc.user_id = '35'
AND alloc.deleted = '0'
AND alloc.acknowledged = '0'
GROUP BY alloc.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you, the IF statement part is good. It's not ideal but it works without me having to re-create the structure for the sake of my naming conventions.